# Wi-Fi very slow except for when another computer uses it

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, latency

We recently moved to a new home in a new state, with a new ISP. I'm a software guy, and I work from home frequently through the vpn, so I ordered the fastest connection they have. Everything works fine for me when I'm using the network at home.

When I'm at work, my wife is constantly complaining about how slow the internet is. Streaming video is basically impossible on her iMac. Latency is through the roof. We pay a lot for our cable+internet, so this was making both of us pretty upset.

She noticed, however, that while I'm at home using my personal computer (over Wi-Fi, having no problems), all of her speed issues disappear. So, she has started using my laptop at home while on her iMac, and everything works. I thought she was crazy, but just this morning I watched as my bank's webpage refused to load on her iMac, so I whipped out my laptop and hit google and the page came right up.

What could possibly be causing this kind of behavior?

Comment: There is a number of issues reported with wireless on OS X. Check out OSXDaily.com for a list of them. Here's one point to get you started: http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/09/quickly-access-wi-fi-diagnostics-os-x/